# Visual Studio 2019 memory profiler tool lists all objects in managed heap as UNKNOWN

Tags: visual-studio, memory, profiler

When using the visual studio 2019 memory usage profiling tool the snapshots don't say what the objects in the managed heap are.

It simply has a lists of objects as follows

Object Type Count   Size (Bytes)    Inclusive Size (Bytes)  Module
 + UNKNOWN 0x7ffd73f09068   80,110  3,204,400   38,414,376
 + UNKNOWN 0x7ffdc6f706e8   57,126  5,719,520   5,719,520
 + UNKNOWN 0x7ffd73cf3d80   49,230  3,718,896   4,110,400

How can i get visual studio to show the actual class names of the objects currently in memory?

For reference i'm developing a .net core 2.2 application.

Comment: Same problem here, did you find solution?

Answer (score 2):

What I found out so far: The problem with the "UNKNOWN" objects only appears if you run the memory profiler via "Analyze > Performance Profiler...", start the memory profiling, take several snapshots.
However, if you start a debug session, open the window "Diagnostic Tools", take several snapshots, you will see proper names of allocated objects.